# How to pass a script argument with run-s to a pre-script task in Node?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-start

I am trying to run a script before the `build` script in a multi module Angular project. The script copies some files so I thought I'd put it in the `prebuild` script. But it seems that this won't get passed at all:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild": "node ./copyscript.js",
        "build": "ng build"
    }
}
```

I thought It'd be possible with `run-s` but I am not able to get it to work.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "run-s \"copy\ -- {1}" && ng build"
    }
}
```

I run the scripts via: `npm run build proj1`.

My attempts so far have failed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "run-s \"build:copy {1}\" \"build:run {@}\" --",
        "build:copy": "node ./copyscript.js",
        "build:run": "ng build"
    }
}
```